# Could not find or load main class JavaInherit

Tags: java

package javainherit;

class Vehicle {

```
String strRegNum;
String strModel;
String strMake;
String strColor;
private String strClassType = "Vehicle:";

String strIgnition;
String strRun;

void turnIgnitionOn() {
    strIgnition = strClassType + " turned ON";
    System.out.println(strIgnition);
}

void run() {
    strRun = strClassType + " is RUNNING";
    System.out.println(strRun);
}
```

}

class Car extends Vehicle {

```
String str1;

Car () {
    str1 = "From the constructor";
}

Car (String str3) {
    str1 = str3 + "From the constructor";
}    

void run() {
    String str = str1 + ":Car is running";
    System.out.println (str);
}

    void run(String str2) {
    System.out.println (str2);
    String str = str2 + ":Car is running";
}
```

}

class JavaInherit {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Vehicle veh = new Vehicle();

    veh.turnIgnitionOn();
    veh.run();

    Car car1 = new Car();
    car1.run();
    car1.run("Overloading:");
    Car car2 = new Car("New Car by default");
    car2.run();
}
```

}

This is my code and I already have the car.class , JavaInherit.class and vehicle.class at the concerned directory.I have already tried all the possible ways explained in stack overflow answers.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you try to execute your program using the main class `JavaInherit`.

Based on the information you provided I assume that the class `JavaInherit` is also located in the package `javainherit` (it is not clear if all classes are in separate files or not). In Java you always have to use the full class name including the package name. 
Therefore the class name is `javainherit.JavaInherit`. And don't forget if you execute your java program on command line the current directory must be the package root (where you see the subdirectory `javahinerit`), not the directory `javainherit` itself!

`java -cp . javainherit.JavaInherit`